# How to perform sort with multiple fields on custom query JPQL with Spring Pageable

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0

I am using Spring's Pageable to sort the columns.

A working example is below:

```
  Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, countOfBookData.intValue(), getSortingDirection(sortingOrder), sortingField);
```

**Where sortingOrder = ASC and sortingField = bookName**

Here is the query

```
 @Query("SELECT bs FROM BookSummary bs WHERE bs.bookId=:bookId")
List<Books> getBookDetails(@Param("bookId") Integer bookId, Pageable pageable)
```

But I got stuck when I need to perform this sort on Custom my custom query.
So I have no idea how I can perform the sorting using Pageable for below custom query:

```
Public List<Tuple> getBookDetails(Integer bookId){
String query = "SELECT book.bookCd as bookCode, "
                + "book.name as bookName"
                + "FROM Book book WHERE book.bookId=:bookId";
        return entityManager.createQuery(query , Tuple.class).setParameter("bookId", bookId).getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same as in the first custom query but using the [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), for example:

```java
public interface BookDetails {
    String getBookCode();
    String getBookName();
}
```

```java
@Query("select b.bookCd as bookCode, b.name as bookName from Book b where b.bookId = ?1")
List<BookDetails> getBookDetails(Integer bookId, Pageable pageable);
```

Note that projection method names must match with corresponding aliases in the query.

Or without the query:

```java
List<BookDetails> getAllById(Integer bookId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Lets say I do have a restriction to use the custom query only. What exact I am looking for is to do the same with custom query not with @Query.

Comment: @DeskToDevelop you have a restriction to use `@Query` annotation or to use Spring Data JPA query methods at all? (see the updated answer)